# Magento 2 add column to attributes set admin grid

Tags: magento2, php

At present, my `Attribute set` grid only has a column `Set`. I want to override 'Attribute set' code to add column `id` into its grid. Where I can find the grid code and How I can change it for suitable?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attribute Set` Grid is from **`vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\layout\catalog_product_set_block.xml`**

Just `override this layout` from your module and add the code below to add the `attribute set id` to the grid

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.catalog.product.set.container">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="adminhtml.catalog.product.set.grid" as="grid">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">setGrid</argument>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Grid\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">set_name</argument>
                    <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                    <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="adminhtml.catalog.product.set.grid.columnSet" as="grid.columnSet">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">setGrid</argument>
                        <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="path" xsi:type="string">catalog/*/edit</item>
                            <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getAttributeSetId</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.catalog.product.set.grid.columnSet.set_id" as="set_id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Id</argument>
                            <argument name="align" xsi:type="string">left</argument>
                            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">attribute_set_id</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>  
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.catalog.product.set.grid.columnSet.set_name" as="set_name">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Set</argument>
                            <argument name="align" xsi:type="string">left</argument>
                            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">attribute_set_name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]